# AsyncStorage before list render React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, use-effect, asyncstorage

I have an app that list incidents of a animals charity ong.

After the login, the ong is directed to your incidents list, so i must pass your ID of login page to load this list.

I'm trying to load the variables of AsyncStorage in a function and then pass it to a callback that load the incidents list in React `useEffect`.

Code:

```
export default function Incidents() {
  const [incidents, setIncidents] = useState([]);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [id, setID] = useState('');
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
```

**loadStorage:**

```
loadStorage = async function(callback) {
    
    try {
      const ongid = await AsyncStorage.getItem('ongID');
      const ongname = await AsyncStorage.getItem('ongName');

      if (ongid && ongname !== null) {
        setID(ongid);
        setName(ongname);
        
      }
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }

    callback();
  }
```

**loadIncidents:**

```
loadIncidents = async function() {

    if (loading) {
      return;
    }

    if (total > 0 && incidents.lenght === total) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      const response = await api.get('profiles', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: id,
        },
        params: { page },
      });
  
      setIncidents([ ... incidents, ... response.data]);
      setTotal(response.headers['x-total-count']);
      setPage(page +1);
      setLoading(false);

    } catch (e) {
      alert(e); //When i access the incident list page i got the error: 'Error: Request failed with status code 400'
    }  
  }
```

**useEffect:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      loadStorage(loadIncidents);
    });
  }, []);
```

The error in the `alert (e)` line of `loadIncidents` happens because `useEffect` is not fully calling the `loadStorage (loadIncidents)` part the first time I enter the application.

I have another page called newIncident, if I navigate to it after pressing OK on this error and go back to the incident list page (by `navite.goBack ()`) the list will be loaded with all the incidents from the logged ONG.

Need this behavior when I first enter the page that lists the ONG's incidents. Since the both methods are asynchronous, i'm not be able to figure out how to do this.

Comment: One problem i see is the callback() should be inside the if block in loadStorage otherwise it would be called even if the ongid is empty

Comment: already tried it but no success. The same error persist.

Comment: if you put a console.log(id) inside loadIncidents do you see a valid token ?

Comment: No, id is empty

Comment: console.log( 'id': + id ) after try catch block  in loadStorage where the if condition was true is empty too.

Comment: And you get the correct id when you return to this screen ?

Comment: Yes. It seems then loadStorage was completily loaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218255/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-rafael-da-silva).

Comment: here is the current code: https://github.com/venuziano/BeTheHero/blob/master/mobile/src/pages/Incidents/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it using promises. code below:

```
async function loadStorage() {
    var ongid = '';
    var ongname = '';

    try {
      ongid = await AsyncStorage.getItem('ongID');
      ongname = await AsyncStorage.getItem('ongName');

    } catch (e) {
      alert(e);
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      if (ongid !== null) {
        setID(ongid);
        setName(ongname);
        const ong = { 'name': ongname, 'id': ongid}

        return resolve(ong);
      }
    })
  }
```

Then in useEffect information loads like this:

```
loadStorage()
 .then(loadIncidents)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider using [react-native-easy-app](https://github.com/chende008/react-native-easy-app/blob/master/README.en-US.md). After completing the initial binding, it can enable you to access the properties in AsyncStorage synchronously in the form of assignment and value, because it is simple enough, so you will not appear above Various problems.